# Is there an R function to predict a continuous outcome variable with 1 binary and 1 ordinal predictor variable nonparametrically?

Tags: r, regression, continuous-data

I have a binary predictor variable (situation1, situation2) and another one that's ordinally scaled (levels in an n-back task, they're called no-back,0-back,1-back & 2-back with 2-back being the highest level). I have a continuous outcome variable (illusion rate).

I wanted to run an ANOVA, but my data is not normally distributed, so I'd like to use a nonparametric test. I thought about using an logistic regression, but I think my outcome variable would have to be binary to be able to do so.

Does anyone have an idea of how I can compute a test like that in R?

Comment: If you just want to predict, there are innumerable ML algorithms that can do that in R but if you're going for some specific interpretability requirements that may narrow your list of choices. This could be a SO question if you're just asking what you can do and how, but if the question is more about what's most statistically preferable then CrossValidated may be the better choice.

Comment: Apparently bootstrapping does the trick. :-)

Comment: Now that this is on CV, you need to tell us more about illusion rate. For example, if illusion rate is essentially continuous, but bounded, that is one kind of model. If the flavour is more: subjects reported an illusion #1 times out of #2 trials then that is another kind. I am guessing wildly, but note that you tell us more about your predictors than about your outcome, and it's the nature of the outcome that drives what is a good idea. In broad terms my guess is some kind of generalized linear model. Note that the marginal distribution of the outcome is irrelevant even for ANOVA.

Comment: Okay so I compute the illusion rate for each block & situation by dividing the # of trials in which an illusion was perceived by all trials in which people could perceive the illusion.

Comment: So, that is to me a binomial generalised linear model. It's not surprising that your outcome is not normally distributed, as it is discrete and bounded. That need not stop means being good summaries of the data.